# 500 internal error suphp

Tags: linux, suphp

I'm using godaddy CentOS, Cpanle, suphp  with easyapache and when i try to hit my php page i get 500 error and following lines in Apache log:

```
[Fri Apr 20 04:23:48 2012] [error] [client 182.178.175.241] SoftException in Application.cpp:422: Mismatch between target UID (99) and UID (502) of file "/home/user/public_html/phpinfo.php"
[Fri Apr 20 04:23:48 2012] [error] [client 182.178.175.241] Premature end of script headers: phpinfo.php
[Fri Apr 20 04:23:48 2012] [error] [client 182.178.175.241] File does not exist: /home/user/public_html/500.shtml
```

I feel that issue is with permission but i font know from where this target user is coming (nobody use of uid 99) and where should i set those permissions. I tried setting phpinfo but no success. can any 1 please help me.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an ownership problem.  The error message seems to say that it requires the UID (i.e the owner) of the file to be 99 but it is currently 502.  My guess is that 502 is your UID and 99 is Apache.  (Actually, judging on the comments in other forums when searching for this error message, it's probably the "nobody" user.)

Try `sudo chown nobody phpinfo.php`

If you have some other method of changing ownership of files through cPanel, feel free to use that instead.

Comment: issue has been resolved by disabling suphp in apache conf. thanks all